# What should I change so that my TCP server is "online"?

Tags: python, twisted

Client (not all the code the part "gestionnaire" is done with classes and is really long)

```
    import tkinter
    import twisted
    from twisted.internet import reactor

    gestionnaire = twisted.internet.protocol.ClientFactory
    gestionnaire.protocol = twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver

    reactor.connectTCP("LocalHost", 8000, gestionnaire)
    twisted.internet.reactor.run()
```

Server: (same as client)

```
    import twisted.internet.protocol
    import twisted.protocols.basic
    import twisted.internet

    factory = twisted.internet.protocol.Factory
    factory.protocol = twisted.protocols.basic.LineReceiver
    twisted.internet.reactor.listenTCP(8000, factory)
    twisted.internet.reactor.run()
```

I think I should change "LocalHost" on the client side but I don't know what to change it with. 
(I just started trying doing TCP servers so I don't know a lot about them)

Comment: you should change it to the actual url / IP address that you server is "reachable" with. You should also consider the port as part of the address (i.e., that might not be `8000` anymore). That's something which is specific on "how" you have put online the server. That's networking details. So, how did you put it online? What server engine are you using? Are you behind a proxy / firewall / cloud stuff etc.. ?

Comment: Also, for your information, `localhost` (and you should keep it in lowercase) is often a shorthand for the IP address `127.0.0.1`, which is by convention a special value, non-routable address that corresponds to the current machine. Also called "loopback" sometimes.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't know that so I'm going to look it up.